# iOS NSDictionary datatype to javascript in phonegap. How to?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ios4, phonegap-plugins

New to phonegap. Less knowledge about scripting.

in iOS Native Code, passing NSDictionary along with CDVCommandStatus_OK 
to java script, as below.

```
  NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"kolaveri", @"Name",nil];
 result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDictionary:dict];
 [self writeJavascript:[result toErrorCallbackString:callbackId]];
```

In JavaScript,

The following Function is getting invoked:

```
  function MySuccessHandler (result) 
    { 
        alert("SUCCESS: \r\n"+result ); 
    }
```

When NSString is passed, the same gets printed in the alert message.

Having passed NSDictionary ,  how to get the key/values in the javascript ?

it prints **[object Object]** in the alert Message.

Kindly provide few pointers on it.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `alert("SUCCESS: \r\n" + JSON.stringify(result) );` to print out the JSON object

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `NSDictionary` to a JSON dictionary/object. If you use iOS5, you can use `NSJSONSerialization` for this.

Comment: Thanks for the  reply; still facing some issue, not sure where i am mistaking. I did the following: Serialized into NSData, and Converted into NSString, and passing to CDVPluginResult with 'messageAsString', and i am unable to parse still in the javascript?

Comment: What does your converted NSString look like? Are you sure the conversion to JSON string succeeded and did not return nil?

Comment: No, the conversion was successful, and in the javascript also, when i print in the alert message i get something like  { "site" : "stack", "over": "flow" }, but i am unable parse as key/value pair from this object for ex: result["site"], from the JS side.

Comment: Well of course you can't access key/values directly. Back in your javascript, you have a string, not an object. Parse that string into a javascript object (easiest way being using the JS `eval` function for example, even if not the safest) before being able to use it as an object and accessing its keys!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and spending time for it. :).  got it working.. I have to use NSMutableDictionary instad of NSDictionary.

Comment: Don't forget to check the tick next to the answer if it solved your problem to mark your question as solved on SO.